# Uncheck Checkbox using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple Checkbox

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1" value="Test" /> Test
</div>
```

MVC 5 renders this html for this checkbox

```
<div class="checker" id="uniform-chkBox1">
   <span class="checked">
     <input type="checkbox" value="Test" id="chkBox1">
   </span>
</div>
```

I want to uncheck this checkbox using Javascript/JQuery but I cannot figure it out. Using Firebug, when I remove the span class "checked" the checkbox gets unchecked but I cannot figure out how to do this in Javascript.

Comment: Show the jQuery you are trying to use to uncheck the box.

Comment: *'but I cannot figure it out'* - What did you try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: Checking/unchecking checkboxes with JavaScript has to be the #1 all time most asked dupe.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your selector. How are you selecting your checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#chkBox1').prop('checked', true)`

checks it off and

`$('#chkBox1').prop('checked', false)` turns if off.

Instead of `prop()`, you can also use `attr()`

If you instead want to just remove the class `checked` from the `span` element. you can do

`$('#uniform-chkBox1 span.checked').removeClass('checked')`

Comment: Your answer is very close, only removing the checked class from span gets it unchecked but now to check it again, it requires 2 clicks. It just doesn't gets checked on first click :(

Comment: Perhaps there's some strange JavaScript is generates to handle this. Why don't you try **both** doing `$('#chkBox1').prop('checked', false)` and `$('#uniform-chkBox1 span.checked').removeClass('checked')` ?

Comment: Thank You very much, First I removed the span class and then set the .prop to false and it is working like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

In your case `$("#chkBox1").prop("checked", false);` will uncheck and `$("#chkBox1").prop("checked", true);` will check.

Run code below to see in action.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#chkBox1").prop("checked"))
    $("#chkBox1").prop("checked", false);
  else
    $("#chkBox1").prop("checked", true);
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="Test" id="chkBox1" checked />
```